# Why do I need to use `@MainActor` when I'm already using `.receive(on: .main)`?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I keep getting a runtime error:

> Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.

This occurs when I'm setting my `@Published` array = to a new value. That setting of the array occurs within a `.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main).sink` block.

Example code:

```swift
class MyClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var movies: [Movie] = []

    var retrievePublisher: AnyCancellable?

    func retrieve() async throws {
        retrievePublisher = (await retrieveMovies()).receive(on: DispatchQueue.main).sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in
        }, receiveValue: { [weak self] newArray in
            guard let self else { return }

            movies = newArray.result
        })
    }
}

func retrieveMovies() async -> AnyPublisher<RetrieveResult<Movie>, CustomError> {
    // ...
}
```

However, if I tag the class with `@MainActor`, the runtime error does not occur anymore.

Additionally, if I set a breakpoint on that movies variable or where I'm setting it, I can observe that everything is indeed occurring on the main thread.

Why is `@MainActor` necessary in this case? What about `.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)` is causing the error: `Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed`?

Comment: What is retrievePublisher?

Comment: Did you tried with assign instead of sink ?

Comment: You don’t. async throws serves no purpose in that function. Get rid of the keywords. Combine can’t be “await”. Also remember that the new Concurrency does not work on threads it works on Actors. That is why you shouldn’t mix with GCD.

Comment: Sorry everyone. Just updated to hopefully make it more clear. The retrieveMovies call is async due to other constraints. I tried to oversimplify my question too much.

Comment: Replace your AnyPublisher with an AsyncStream, don’t mix Combine with the new async/await.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `async` code you can just remove Combine's `ObservableObject` and use the `.task` modifier which behind the scenes creates a reference type that gives the async work a lifetime tied to the UI, e.g.

```
@State var movies: [Movie] = []
...
.task { // runs when this UI appears and cancelled if it dissapears
    movies = await retrieveMovies()
}
```

Back to your Combine `ObservableObject`: It's a mistake to use `sink` because then the lifetime of the pipeline isn't tied to the object, the correct operator to complete a pipeline in an `ObservableObject` is [`assign(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/assign(to:)) an `@Published`. It's also a mistake to set up a pipeline in a func, the pipeline should be set up in `init` and then it can work on incoming data automatically. Finally it's usually a mistake to use Combine if you aren't using any of the combing operators like `combine`, `merge`, `zip` etc. This all being said, you can avoid all of this by just removing the Combine `ObservableObject` completely and just use `.task` and `.task(id:)` when you want it to restart if something (that is the `id`) changes.

Comment: So `retrieveMovies` is async and returns `AnyPublisher<RetrieveResult<Movie>, CustomError>`. Because we want to retrieve new movies as they are retrieved. However the setup process needs to be awaited.

Comment: I'm not seeing an `assign` on that.

Comment: If you want to use Combine publishers then you need to remove the async code. But that would not be recommended given that async is new and Combine hasn't been updated in over 3 years.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/assign(to:)